# unable to enumerate USB3 device

Tags: usb, hp, xhci-hcd

When I plug my HP 1102w printer into my USB for setup, the kernel logs a series of messages:

```
...  kernel: [  381.876303] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
...  kernel: [  381.988278] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
...  kernel: [  382.204269] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
...  kernel: [  382.420262] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
...  kernel: [  382.532273] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
...  kernel: [  382.748288] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
...  kernel: [  382.964280] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
...  kernel: [  382.964407] usb 3-3: Device not responding to setup address.
...  kernel: [  383.168362] usb 3-3: Device not responding to setup address.
...  kernel: [  383.372297] usb 3-3: device not accepting address 19, error -71
...  kernel: [  383.484271] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
...  kernel: [  383.484396] usb 3-3: Device not responding to setup address.
...  kernel: [  383.688397] usb 3-3: Device not responding to setup address.
...  kernel: [  383.892291] usb 3-3: device not accepting address 20, error -71
...  kernel: [  383.892326] usb usb3-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
...  kernel: [  402.061201] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 16
```

As a result, I cannot set up this printer.  (I had it working before over Wifi, but it stopped connecting for no good reason, and I need to set it up with the USB cable.)

I verified that several USB thumb drives still work on the same port.

My box is now running kernel 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64

I read on an old thread that someone fixed a similar problem by disabling IO MMU in his BIOS.  On my Gigabyte motherboard setup, this is labelled as "Inter Virtualization Technology".  I disabled it, but the result hasn't changed.

Is this likely a problem with my USB driver, motherboard, or HP 1102w printer?  What else can I do to diagnose it?